# Is this jquery-migrate-1.2.0 error of concern?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-migrate

Poking around with Google developer tools while my asp.net project was running on Chrome, it flags "jquery-migrate-1.2.0.min.js" on the Resources tab, Scripts section, with: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

Is this something I should worry about? If so, how to resolve the problem -- revert to an older version of migrate, or...???

### UPDATE

Now it's gone, although the only thing I did different was swap out the minified version of jquery 1.9.1 for the "debug" version.

Comment: Does it also happen with the previous version of jQuery Migrate? What version of jQuery are you using it with, and what version of jQuery did you have previously? that doesn't look like an error i'd ignore.

Comment: Uncaught errors inside jQuery usually mean you're calling something incorrectly, although it's remotely possible it's a bug in jQuery.

Comment: You need to look at the call stack, to see what jQuery function your application was calling when this error happened.

Comment: @Kevin B. - I just added migrate to the project, as I upgraded this app from using jquery 1.6.2 to 1.9.1